# Python Program homework

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to write a program that brings in a file and it asks to input an account number and if it matches a number on the file it will tell the user it is either valid or invalid.

The program runs but always says invalid no matter what. What's wrong?

Here's the code:

```
def main():

    try:    
        file = open('charge_accounts.txt','r') 

        acc_num = file.readlines()    
        starting_index = 0      

        while(starting_index != len(acc_num)):    
            acc_num[starting_index] = 0 
            int(acc_num[starting_index])                    
            starting_index += 1 
            search = int(input('Enter Account Number:'))    

            if(search in acc_num):  
                print(search,':Yes, the account number is VALID')
            else:   
                print(search,':No, the account number is INVALID')

        file.close()        

    except ValueError:  
        print('Unable to open the file')

main()
```

Comment: Hint: `search` is an `int`, but `acc_num` is a `list`, so `search in acc_num` will always be `False`. Try removing the `int()` after getting `input()` and see what happens. Also, watch out for the `\n`s in `acc_num`

Answer (score 0):

```
acc_num[starting_index] = 0  
//this sets 0 .. In the last while pass
//acc_num will value [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,]

int(acc_num[starting_index]) 
//This does nothing

starting_index += 1 
search = int(input('Enter Account Number:'))
// Above search is set as int.
// Bellow search should be a string. 
if(search in acc_num):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

try:    
    file = open('charge_accounts.txt','r') 
    search = input('Enter Account Number:')
    acc_num = file.readlines()    

    for x in acc_num:
        if search in x:
            print "Yup"

    file.close()        

except ValueError:  
    print('Unable to open the file')
```

main()

If you are reading a text file everything is read as a string. "12345" is not the same as 12345. First is a string. If every line is just an integer, you could write var = int(input(.......)) (after sanitizing for non-ints) and then compare against an int, but likely not necessary for what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have these account number in charge_accounts.txt

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

When python execute this line --> `acc_num = file.readlines()`

acc_num will have these :-

```
ipdb> acc_num
['12345\n', '23456\n', '34567\n', '45678\n', '56789']
```

Why you set the first item in list to 0?

```
acc_num[starting_index] = 0

ipdb> acc_num
[0, '23456\n', '34567\n', '45678\n', '56789']
```

And the last hint according to mshsayem:

your list is string and your search is int. Remove the int() and set str for your input.

```
Enter Account Number:56789
('56789', ':Yes, the account number is VALID')
```

Last but not least, try using pdb/ipdb to debug.

Comment: This was great.  I appreciate everyone helping.  I took out the returns and got rid of the things that were not needed and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider changing your program to the following:

```
def main():

    try:    
        with open('charge_accounts.txt','r') as f:
            acc_num = f.read().splitlines() 
        starting_index = 0      

        while(starting_index != len(acc_num)):    
            search = raw_input('Enter Account Number:')
            starting_index += 1 
            if(search in acc_num):  
                print(search,':Yes, the account number is VALID')
            else:   
                print(search,':No, the account number is INVALID')
        f.close()
        return

    except ValueError:  
        print('Unable to open the file')
        return

main()
```

This eliminates the '\n' characters from acc_num, and using raw_input reads string and now your search comparison finds the account number(s).